# Bash - How to print multi line strings (with '\n') using printf

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

i'm trying to print a multi line strings in `printf` this way

```
printf "hi\n"
printf "next line here\n"
```

I can't do the following

```
text_content="
hi
next line here
"

printf $text_content
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: in what way does `printf "$text_content"` *not* work? It replicates the native new-lines in the assignment, as well as converting the `\n` to newlines for me as well. If you don't quote it, then word splitting would cause only the first word to be displayed

Comment: Why do you have both `\n` and embedded newlines in `text_content`?

Comment: @chepner my mistake, edited

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoting the variable should do the trick. In your example, however, you are getting double newlines.

```
printf "$text_content"
```

Comment: If the variable has any `%` symbols it may be better to use `printf "%s\n" "$variable"`

Comment: You really should always use a format string as the first argument, and quote all variables. `printf '%s\n' "$text_content"` (perhaps without the `\n` if the variable already contains all the newlines you want). See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 15):

Here's another variation.

```
printf '%s\n' 'first line here' 'second line here'
```

You can add an arbitrary number of arguments; `printf` will repeat the format string until all arguments are exhausted.

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/sh' \
    'for x; do' \
    '    echo "Welcome to my script!"' \
    'done' >script.sh
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. It makes use of bash line-continuation, a single printf format which does not need to be repeated, and avoids the [echo portability problems](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/)

Answer (score 1):

If printf is not necessary, then you may use echo:

```
var="one\ntwo"
echo -e $var
```

Comment: This is bad advice. `printf` was introduced precisely because `echo -e` is brittle and unportable.

Comment: that is reason, why i say "If printf is not necessary"

Comment: @Andrew iow, "if reliability is not necessary, just use echo"